# What are the stepps to this shortcut?

Tags: factorial

I looked at an answer for a question and I don't know how they came to this conclusion.

$(k+1)!-1 + (k+1)!(k+1) = (k+2)! - 1$

What are the stepps behind it?

Comment: Factorise $(k+1)!$

Comment: I upvoted because I couldn't see a reason to downvote.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(k+1)! + (k+1)!(k+1) = (k+1)! (1 + (k+1)) = (k+2)!.$